# Autohotkey Simple ControlSend to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

**EDIT for working version**

```
!j::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

ControlGet, OutputVar, Hwnd,,Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1, Google Chrome

ControlFocus,,ahk_id %outputvar%


ControlSend, , {Space} , Google Chrome
```

Original post:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, on
!j::
IfWinExist, ahk_exe chrome.exe
ControlSend, ahk_exe chrome.exe, {SPACE}
return
```

What I want is to be able to toggle Play/Pause on a youtube video that is playing through chrome. The chrome window is not the active window, but is showing on my second monitor. I've tried using the ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 from WindowSpy and also doing a ControlClick with the ClassNN: Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1 but nothing seems to properly send a {SPACE} or CLICK to pause the video.

WindowSpy info (the video title will not be consistent):

```
Calculus 2 Lecture 10.2: Introduction to Parametric Equations - YouTube - Google Chrome
ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
ahk_exe chrome.exe

Absolute:   -908, 634 (less often used)
Relative:   1012, 634 (default)
Client: 1012, 634 (recommended)

ClassNN:    Intermediate D3D Window1
Text:   
Color:  05070D (Red=05 Green=07 Blue=0D)
    x: 0    y: 0    w: 1920 h: 1080
Client: x: 0    y: 0    w: 1920 h: 1080

Chrome Legacy Window
Chrome Legacy Window

Chrome Legacy Window
Chrome Legacy Window
```

Answer (score 1):

Do consult with documentation first: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm

```
ControlSend, Control, Keys, WinTitle
```

while you have

```
ControlSend, ahk_exe chrome.exe, {SPACE}
```

`ahk_exe chrome.exe` is considered as [valid `WinTitle`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) parameter, **NOT** as valid `Control`.

Therefore, what you want is:

```
ControlSend,,{SPACE},ahk_exe chrome.exe
```

Additionally, as you can read in [`ControlSend`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm) documentation:

> If this (**`Control`**) parameter is blank or omitted, the target window's topmost
>   control will be used. If this parameter is `ahk_parent`, the keystrokes
>   will be sent directly to the target window instead of one of its
>   controls

So if above line of code does not work for you, you might want to use:

```
ControlSend,ahk_parent,{SPACE},ahk_exe chrome.exe
```